# Subclass NSManagedObject and app name on chinese language

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

i dev app with name on chinese language. And today i have error from CoreData:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named '￐ﾟ￐ﾣ￐ﾝ￐ﾚ.' for entity 'Messages'.
```

i think xcode doesnt understand symbols in Class field in entity in data model. i have read a lot of articles, and i know that it needs to write AppName.ClassName. But in all examples appName is English and i have chinese. So i cant change app name because it will be rejected. 
i think may be there are some constants that i can use instead of my app name. i dont know. help me please to figure out it.

Comment: Do you have a subclass of `NSManagedObject` in your project that has that class name?

Comment: I get the same result. It looks like a bug in Xcode to me.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem with one line of code before class declaration

```
@objc(Messages)
class Messages: NSManagedObject {
```

after adding first line i can use 'Messages' in Entity->Class without AppName prefix.

Comment: It's still a bug, because you shouldn't need to do that. You should file this bug with Apple so that it gets fixed.